# Changing Eclipse Error Language

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm just trying to change the language for all messages I got from eclipse into english. Atm they are all in my native os language, except the interface of eclipse.
The "problems" list however still remains German after trying to set some Arguments.
I've tried the following so far:
-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -J-Duser.language=en
in my JRE's Default VM arguments, but it doesn't change anything.
Does anybody know how to change to display everything in english?

Cheers Max

Comment: What operating system? Have you tried placing those arguments in your `eclipse.ini` file?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm on a Win 8.1 x64, I'll try changing the eclipse.ini and get back to you in a minute

Comment: Didn't change anything :/ Still german

Comment: Try This:  Add -Duser.language=en before before the -vmargs params into eclipse.ini then restart your eclipse.

Comment: Hm might it be, that I'm in an YXML file or shouldnt that be of any interest?

Answer (score 0):

You can start Eclipse with the console arguments `-nl en`. To set this permanently, put `-nl=en` into `eclipse.ini`.

Source: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/266397/